# I want to add zoom effect on click of product images

Tags: product, product-images

I have attached the screenshot of before and after zoom

[image]

after on click the should be like

[image: after click]

Comment: It's for Magento 2 PDP?

Comment: It's magento 2 but i don't want to add size chart but just want to add zoom 50% on click without opening the image as an alert box

Answer (score 0):

You can enable on view.xml

**app/design/frontend/Package/theme/etc/view.xml**

```
<var name="magnifier">
        <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
        <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
        <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
        <var name="width">400</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
        <var name="height">400</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
        <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
        <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
</var>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this freebie extension :

https://store.ibnab.com/magento-2-extensions/magento-2-quick-cloud-zoom.html

Demo : https://youtu.be/evNiJFGrcio

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Magic Zoom Magento 2 extension. It can zoom internally, so no popup/modal:

https://marketplace.magento.com/magictoolbox-magiczoom.html

On the settings page, set the Position to Inner.

[image: Settings page for internal zoom on Magento 2 Magic Zoom]